# jomsocial force status refresh

Tags: joomla2.5, jomsocial

I am getting crazy to make jomsocial 2.6.2 with joomla 2.5.7 to works.

The problem is that when a user change the status the message is not reflecting in the wall.

Only if you refresh the page or switch view all to me and Friends view.

There no js error in the console and i get:

```
Jax.submitTask ajax_1.3.js:1
Jax.call ajax_1.3.js:1
joms.extend.activities.getLatestContent script-1.2.js:226
reloadActivities myaccount:1129
(anonymous function)
```

But no refresh anybody know how to force the wall so i can add a line after:

```
Status.submit
```

in

```
status.form.php
```

any tip welcome 2 days already trying...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I can believe that it is working

I add this line at the status.forum.php forcing to load all status

line 255

```
complete: function()
{
  CreatorLoadingIndicator.hide();
  joms.ajax.call('frontpage,ajaxGetActivities', [ 'all' ])
  Status.reset();
  Status.submitting = false;
}
```